# Why doesn't grep remove lines of terminal output from find command by default?

Tags: bash, shell, grep, find, pipe

I am constantly frustrated by this simple command:

```
find / | fgrep somestuff.ext
```

When I don't use `sudo`, I get line after line of permission denied - which is fair enough, but why isn't this output ignored when grep reads it from pipe?

Why is this form of output sent straight to the terminal window and not passed into the pipe (what I suspect must be happening) and subsequently ignored by grep, while the same lines produced by cat (say I had permission denied messages stored in a text file) would correctly go into the pipe and be ignored by my grep pattern?

I feel like there is something about the STDIN/STDOUT process I'm not understanding here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The permission denied messages are not sent to stdout from `find` but to stderr. You can redirect the whole stderr to the bit bucket:

```
find 2>/dev/null | fgrep somestuff.ext
```

Also, to find the given file, you don't need any grepping:

```
find . -name somestuff.ext
```

to which you can still apply the `2>/dev/null`.

To only suppress the permission denied messages, you can use

```
2> >(grep -v 'Permission denied' >&2)
```

in bash.

Comment: I see - and to further clarify, the pipe then normally connects the fd of 2 processes, in my case I'm connecting standard output produced by find / to grep, which reads from standard input. So maybe it's the need for pipe I don't get here, if grep just blindly reads standard input anyway, why do I need a pipe? Why couldn't I say: "find / & grep stuff" or "find / > grep stuff" instead? (To be clearer yet, I understand why those examples SPECIFICALLY will fail, but conceptually I still don't understand)

Why do I pipe output to grep if it only cares about the global standard input anyway?

Comment: `find . | fgrep somestuff.ext` looks for `somestuff.ext` anywhere in the line (which means it's broken for multiline file paths) while `find . -name somestuff.ext` only matches the filename portion exactly. `find . -path '*somestuff.ext*'` would be a closer equivalent (and fix the problems with multiline file paths but introduce one with filenames containing sequences of bytes not forming valid characters).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: I guess `.ext` means extension, so searching for `.ext*` is doing more than they need. But the edge cases are important to consider, especially when you don't manually check the results and the script does something important to the selected files.

Comment: @MJHd: Why you pipe output to grep is something you should know. Probably because you don't know how to process the stderr?

Comment: Sorry, I think there may be a bit of language barrier here, but I specifically said I understand why these examples will actually fail - the question is about the logic of the relationship. The examples I gave were illustrative of the logical disconnect I'm having, I understand they make no sense for all the reasons you state - that's why I prefaced the way I did. And YES - I "don't know how to process the stderr" (hence this question) 

I'll try to rephrase -> one moment

Comment: I tried to show you how to process stderr - use redirection. You can read more about redirection in the manual page of your shell, e.g. `man bash`.

Comment: You probably want `2> >(grep -v 'Permission denied' >&2)` to avoid polluting stdout.

Comment: Thank you so much for all the help, again, I really wasn't looking for a solution to this specific problem as I don't want a fish - I want to learn to fish. 
George's answer explains that it is the behavior of pipe I was misunderstanding, and how it behaves vs how I thought it was behaving...
Thank's for taking the time though! Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

While the nice answer of choroba cures your problem, the reason for the behavior you have noticed is the default pipeline behavior in bash (and i suppose in most of the shells as well).

As described in `man bash` pipelines section:

> The standard output of command is connected via a pipe to the standard
>   input of  command2.   This  connection  is  performed
>          before any redirections specified by the command (see REDIRECTION below).

Meaning that `stderr` of `command1` is not by default fed to `command2` through the pipe but is driven to your tty, the default stderr link.

Bash manual also says:

> If |& is used, command's standard error, in addition to its standard output, is connected to command2's standard input through the pipe; it is shorthand for 2>&1  |.

So in your case, if you want to pipe to grep command, the find command errors which by default are sent to `/dev/stderr` you need to use one of these two forms:

```
find / |& fgrep somestuff.ext
find / 2>&1 | fgrep somestuff.ext
```

Your queston could be also titled like "Why stderr is ignored by pipes".

And the answer is because this is how bash and linux are made by default; to treat `stdout` differently than `stderr`, in order user to be capable to log/treat those two outputs differently.
For example you can pipe `stdout` of command1 to `stdin` of command2 and on the same time you can send `stderr` of command1 to a log file using `2>errorlog.txt`.

Actually when you run a command without any redirections specified like

```
find /
```

It is equivallent to

```
find / 1>/dev/stdout 2>/dev/stderr
```

Which is finally resolved to:

```
find / 1>/dev/tty1 2>/dev/tty1 #assuming that you are logged in tty1
```

as can be verified by a single `ls`:

```
ls -all /dev/st*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Nov 25 15:36 /dev/stderr -> /proc/self/fd/2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Nov 25 15:36 /dev/stdin -> /proc/self/fd/0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Nov 25 15:36 /dev/stdout -> /proc/self/fd/1

ls -all /proc/self/fd/2
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Nov 28 02:46 /proc/self/fd/2 -> /dev/tty1

ls -all /proc/self/fd/1
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Nov 28 02:46 /proc/self/fd/1 -> /dev/tty1
```

If for any reason you want to "join" `stdout` and `stderr` of a command, then you need to explicitly declare your purposes to `bash` using `|&` (for pipelines) or `2>&1` (for any kind of output redirection)